# Setting Linq2Db to read and update with CHAR type and NOT NULL constraint in Oracle

Tags: oracle, linq2db

Reading value of fixed CHAR string from table, using Linq2db Oracle provider:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
    (pk                         NUMBER(15,0) NOT NULL,
     fixed_data                 CHAR(20) DEFAULT ' ' NOT NULL)
```

Although in database, length of FIXED_DATA filed is 20,

```
SELECT LENGTH(fixed_data) FROM mytable WHERE pk = 1 

-- result is 20
```

When same field is read using Linq2Db, value gets truncated to empty string:

```
var row = (from row in database.mytable where row.pk == 1 select row).ToList()[0];
Console.WriteLine(row.fixed_data.Length);

// result is zero
```

This causes problem when record is updated using Linq2Db, Oracle converts empty string to NULL, and UPDATE fails:

```
database.Update(row);

// Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: 'ORA-01407: cannot update ("MYSCHEMA"."MYTABLE"."FIXED_DATA") to NULL
```

Is there any setting in Linq2Db for read->update cycle to work with CHAR type and NOT NULL constraint?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, thanks to source code openly available. By default, Linq2Db calls expression IDataReader.GetString(int).TrimEnd(' ') on every CHAR and NCHAR column. However this can be easily customized, by implementing custom provider, which overrides field value retrieval expression, with one that does not trim:

```
class MyOracleProvider : OracleDataProvider
{
    public MyOracleProvider(string name)
        : base(name)
    {
        // original is SetCharField("Char",  (r,i) => r.GetString(i).TrimEnd(' '));
        SetCharField("Char", (r, i) => r.GetString(i));
        // original is SetCharField("NChar", (r,i) => r.GetString(i).TrimEnd(' '));
        SetCharField("NChar", (r, i) => r.GetString(i));
    }
}
```